# Spring Boot 2.7.5 Security 401 Unuathorized

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, http-status-code-401

I'm struggling with 401 unuathorized in postman while i try to enter a secured endpoint, I'm passing correct data, but spring security doesn't pass me on, I think I might miss something in DetailsService or somewhere 
 Creating new user

[image]

Trying to authorize
[image]

Security config

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    private final CustomAuthProvider provider;
    private final AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        builder.authenticationProvider(provider);
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/register").permitAll();
                    auth.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").hasRole("USER");
                    auth.antMatchers("/user/**").permitAll();
                    auth.antMatchers("/getusers").hasRole("USER");
                    auth.antMatchers("/moderator/**").hasRole("MODERATOR");
                    auth.antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
                })
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS);
        return http.build();
    }
```

Details Service

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor // Generates a constructor with required arguments.
public class DetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        var user = userService.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Couldn't find \""+ username +"\" username");
        }
        if (user.getRoles() == null || user.getRoles().isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("User \"" + username + "\" has no roles");
        }

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getRoles().stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.isActive(),
                !user.isExpired(), !user.isCredentialsexpired(), !user.isBlocked(), authorities);
    }
```

Method with creating roles

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class ApplicationStartRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Role roleUser = new Role(1L, "123", "ROLE_USER");
        Role roleModerator = new Role(2L, "456", "ROLE_MODERATOR");
        Role roleAdmin = new Role(3L, "789", "ROLE_ADMIN");

        roleRepository.saveAll(List.of(roleUser, roleAdmin, roleModerator));
    }
```

EDIT: That's my password encoder bean

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

And register method

```
    @Override
    public UserDTO createUser(RegisterDTO user) {
        if (user.equals(userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername()))) {
            throw new RuntimeException("This nickname is already taken");
        }
        if (user.equals(userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail()))) {
            throw new RuntimeException("This email is already taken");
        }
        // Encoding password
        user.setPassword(encoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        // On creating new Account it's going to have USER role
        Role role = roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_USER");

        String username = user.getUsername();
        String password = user.getPassword();
        String email = user.getEmail();

        User dto = buildUser(username, password, email, role);

        userRepository.save(dto);
        return UserDTO.builder()
                .username(username)
                .password(password)
                .email(email)
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: You probably haven't given your newly registered user the "USER" role.

Comment: Please show us your `PasswordEncoder` bean and your register method.

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio I edited post with PasswordEncoder and register method, also there is a method where I save roles in db

Answer (score 0):

I think this is pretty clear.

That /getusers endpoint is protected and user must have USER role which obviously don't have. By default I think it should be ROLE_USER as spring is using that ROLE_ prefix. But you can specify any role that should be fetched from DB during user authorization.

Comment: I edited post and there is method that hardcode roles and also method where I create new user and assign them a user role